# How to prevent update statement from setting some records to null?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm trying to run an update on one table with an existing table using the query below. The code column records need to be updated but only some of them. My query seems to work but any records that were supposed to be left alone in the code column end up being set to NULL. How can I modify this query to leave those records untouched?

Query

```
update t1 x
set x.code =
(select code from
(select distinct address, city, prov, aflag, rcode from t2) y
where x.address = y.address and x.city = y.city and x.state = y.state and x.flag = y.flag)
where x.aflag like '%b%';
```

Table 1: Code to be updated

```
   t1               
address city    state   flag    code
123      aaa      il     b       400
567      bbb      il     b       400
345      bbb      il     b      -500
789      ddd      il     b       600
546      ccc      il     b       700
```

Table 2: Code column to be used to update T1

```
t2              
address city    state   flag    code
   123   aaa      il      b     -555
   444   bbb      il      b     -555
   345   bbb      il      b     -555
   888   kkk      il      b     -555
   546   ccc      il      b     -555



What the query currently outputs

     current output             
    address city    state   flag    code
       123   aaa      il      b     400
       444   bbb      il      b     NULL
       345   bbb      il      b     -500
       888   kkk      il      b     NULL
       546   ccc      il      b     -700
```

I want the query to leave the records untouched that don't have a match from the update table like below

```
  What I want               
address city    state   flag    code
  123    aaa      il      b     400
  444    bbb      il      b    -555
  345    bbb      il      b    -500
  888    kkk      il      b    -555
  546    ccc      il      b    -700
```

Thanks!

Comment: and a where clause saying where code is not null

Comment: You say you want to update t1 but you show the address from t2 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use `exists` in the `where` clause:

```
update t1 x
    set x.code = (select code
                  from t2 y
                  where x.address = y.address and x.city = y.city and x.state = y.state and x.flag = y.flag and rownum = 1
                 )
    where x.aflag like '%b%' and
          exists (select code
                  from t2 y
                  where x.address = y.address and x.city = y.city and x.state = y.state and x.flag = y.flag and rownum = 1
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

`t2` shall both tell you which rows to update and with which value. For this to happen write an updatetable query:

```
update
(
  select t1.code, t2.code as new_code
  from t1
  join t2 on  t2.address = t1.address
          and t2.city    = t1.city city 
          and t2.state   = t1.state
          and t2.flag    = t1.flag
  where t1.flag like '%b%'
)
set code = new_code;
```

For this to work, `address, city, state, flag` must be unique in `t2`, so the DBMS knows it's getting precisely one record with the update data.

Updatetable queries are especially usefull by the way for such situations where you want to update more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

Some people like it, some don't. It looks surprisingly similar to your original update statement:

```
MERGE INTO t1 x
USING (SELECT DISTINCT address, city, state, flag, code from t2) y
   ON (x.address = y.address AND x.city = y.city AND x.state = y.state AND x.flag = y.flag)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET x.code = y.code
       WHERE x.flag LIKE '%b%';
```